# How to set iterm2 tab title to that of a running tmux session name?

Tags: macos, shell, zsh, tmux, iterm

i know tmux display-message -p '#S' will display the current tmux session name, but i donno how to set the current tmux session name to the iterm2 tab title?

This would really help me to distinguish the various tmux sessions that i am running concurrently and jump to the correct tab rightaway.

Comment: i figured out a workaround.
while starting

    echo "tmux new -s whirr" > whirrtmux.sh
    ./whirrtmux.sh

Since Iterm always display the current command that running, it will display "./whirrtmux.sh" in the tab title.

if anyone has a better way to do this... please let me know

Answer (score 17):

add these to your ~/.tmux.conf:

```
set-option -g set-titles on
set-option -g set-titles-string "#{session_name} - #{host}"
```

Comment: btw, need to uncomment DISABLE_AUTO_TITLE="true" in ~/.zshrc if using zsh.

Comment: Worked perfectly for me, I'm using zsh and did not need to set the config mentioned by Yu-Lin above

Comment: It adds a "(tmux)" string after the session name. Was wondering if that could be removed? That aside, it worked great.

Answer (score 2):

My workflow is usually centered around panes, and I don't use tmux, so I used a slight variation of @mislav answer:

```
set_terminal_tab_title() {
  print -Pn "\e]1;$TABTITLE:q\a"
}

precmd_functions=($precmd_functions set_terminal_tab_title)
```

I threw that into my zshrc; then, in each pane, I `export TABTITLE='FOO'`. That way, when I switch panes, I get the title I want on the tab.

Answer (score 1):

Stick this in your `~/.zshrc`:

```
set_terminal_tab_title() {
  print -Pn "\e]1;$1:q\a"
}

indicate_tmux_session_in_terminal() {
  set_terminal_tab_title "$(tmux display-message -p '#S')"
}

precmd_functions=($precmd_functions indicate_tmux_session_in_terminal)
```

`precmd_functions` is an array that in zsh contains the list of functions to call prior to showing the prompt. If you add your own function to the list, it will get called whenever the prompt is shown, making it a good place to periodically update the terminal tab title.

Comment: aren't you missing a `autoload -U add-zsh-hook`?

Comment: No, because I'm not using `add-zsh-hook`.

Comment: Isn't a condition to check if a session does exist required; somehow I am getting the message: `can't establish current session` when I try to do `source ~/.zshrc`.

Comment: Never seen that error message before. AFAIK, it's not possible to operate inside tmux without being in a context of a session.

Answer (score 1):

Bash Version to display Hello World as a title:

```
echo -ne "\033]0; Hello World \007"
```

And if you want title refreshed each time bash print your prompt:

```
export PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033]0;${USER}@${HOSTNAME%%.*}: ${PWD/#$HOME/~}\007"'
```

Found it on http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20031015173932306